# Why will this code not work when trying to add labels to panels

Tags: c#, label, panel

The screenshot shows part of my code and I am getting the error cannot be used as a method and I'm not sure how to fix it. I want to add labels to the panels that are created for a calendar. Any help will be appreciated.

```
public partial class frmDisplayAppointment : Form
{
    public frmDisplayAppointment()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private List<FlowLayoutPanel> listFlDay = new List<FlowLayoutPanel>();

    private void DisplayAppointment_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GenerateDayPanel(42);
        AddLabelDayToFlDay(1);
    }

    private void GenerateDayPanel(int totalDays)
    {
        flDays.Controls.Clear();

        for (int i = 1; i <= totalDays; i++)
        {
            FlowLayoutPanel fl = new FlowLayoutPanel();
            fl.Name = $"flDay{i}";
            fl.Size = new Size(94, 70);
            fl.BackColor = Color.White;
            fl.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
            flDays.Controls.Add(fl);
            listFlDay.Add(fl);
        }
    }

    private void AddLabelDayToFlDay(int startDay)
    {
        int day = 1;

        for (int i = startDay; i <= listFlDay.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            Label lbl = new Label();
            lbl.Name = $"lblDay{i}";
            lbl.AutoSize = false;
            lbl.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
            lbl.Size = new Size(95, 23);

            lbl.Text = day.ToString() ;
            
            //ERROR HERE
            listFlDay(i).Controls.Add(lbl);

            day += 1;
        }
    }
```

Many thanks

Comment: c# uses brackets to specifiy an index: `listFlDay[i]...`

Comment: @LarsTech Thankyou so much apprieciate it alot